# Hspice subckt naming convention

Tags: hspice

I have a subckt def:

```
.subckt test_L1.2u_W0.14u x y
  . . . . . . 
.ends test_L1.2u_W0.14u
```

I define another subckt which calls the above subckt `test_L1.2u_W0.14u`

```
.subckt top
Xt1 x1 y1 test_L1.2u_W0.14u
Xt2 x2 y2 test_L1.2u_W0.14u
.ends top
```

The error notifies that `test_L1.2u_W0.14u` did not exist.

I create a testbench in which remove the `.` In the subckt definition, and it runs without error.
So does hspice care about `.` In naming convention of subckt. If so, could you provide me some docs relating to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for HSPICE is not well-defined, at least not well-documented. The manual states that it takes a type *subnam*.

Turning to the original [SPICE](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/IcBook/SPICE/UserGuide/description_fr.html), at least we find *something*:

> A name field must begin with a letter (A through Z) and cannot contain any delimiters.

However, what is a *delimiter* is left to your imagination. You have just found that `.` is a delimiter.

An unqualified guess is that you can get close by looking at the documentation for a lot of other programming languages, most notably Fortran and C. Identifiers must start with a letter or underscore, then continue with a sequence of letters, numbers or underscores.